# Capitalization of articles in titles when moved to the end

Tags: articles, noms-propres, majuscules

A client doesn't want to order items using initial *la*, *le*, *de*, etc. but instead by the first « important » word. Some of the phrases are trademarks, so we can't just omit these words. In the client's system, the only way we can do that is to move these small words to the end :

E.g.

*La Banque de Nouvelle-Écosse*

Becomes :

*Banque de Nouvelle-Écosse, La*

When it is moved to the end like this, should « *La/la* » be capitalized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When writing an alphabetical index, parenthesis are used to separate words moved to the end of a sentence, not a comma.
- Normally, articles are not capitalized unless they need to for some other reason, for example for being the first word of a sentence like: *La Banque…*
- The owners of a brand name are free to use, break, impose the rules they like.
- Here, the article is technically still the very same one that used to be at the beginning of the phrase, so its uppercase L should be kept as is:

> Banque de Nouvelle-Écosse (La)